# Sent name of file from Get metadata to Copy data in ADF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I created a pipeline to pass the filename from the container to the Copy Data task.

[image]

I need the file that will appear there (with a different name) to be passed to Copy data and then its contents copied to Snowflake.

[image]

I can't figure out the variables, how to pass it to copy data?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the file name from the get metadata activity to copy activity, you can use the below expression in the source dataset file name of copy activity.

```
@activity('<get metadata actitvity name>').output.childItems[0].Name
```

[image]

Ignore the warning `'activity is not a recognized function`

[image]

When this expression is given, copy activity is executed without error.